# Unity/C# - Set position and rotation manually of object based on another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have 3 objects in 3D Space, but they are only 2D representations of the 3D object. Object A (Obj-A) is the parent object, and 2 different objects (Obj-B, Obj-C) that are not attached to Obj-A as a child, but I have to move along as if they were its child. I am moving and rotating Obj-A, and I am setting Obj-B and Obj-C's positions based on Obj-A with an offset sort of like this:

```
objB.transform.position = objA.transform.position + offset;
objC.transform.position = objA.transform.position - offset;
```

But of course, when Obj-A rotates, I want Obj-B and Obj-C's position to be affected by its rotation as well.
When I rotate Obj-B and Obj-C based on the same logic as Obj-A, they only rotate on their local axis. 
Basically it should look like this:

[image: Expected result]

I am working on Unity, but this part of the project is computed on a C# script independent from Unity. With this, I only have access to the objects' transform positions and the rotation angle, and simply adding Obj-B and Obj-C as children to Obj-A is off the table.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: There are many moveement scripts around where this is done, where for example it will make a camera follow a player without being a child.  What exactly is the bit you dont understand

Comment: in the right two images the `C` is placed differently relative to `A` then in the left two images .. I guess this is an accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should copy the rotation like

```c#
objB.transform.rotation = objA.transform.rotation;
objC.transform.rotation = objA.transform.rotation;
```

then you should use the `offset` componentwise with the local coordinate system of `objA`:

```c#
objB.transform.position = objA.transform.position 
                          + offset.x * objA.transform.right
                          + offset.y * objA.transform.up
                          + offset.z * objA.transform.forward;

objB.transform.position = objA.transform.position 
                          - offset.x * objA.transform.right
                          - offset.y * objA.transform.up
                          - offset.z * objA.transform.forward;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I tried it out but unfortunately, this isn't working for me. I'm not exactly working with Unity objects here, so I had to translate them to what's similar because some of the values you mentioned are not available. For instance, it only uses a Transform2D so there's no Z value .

Comment: No you are using [`GameObject.transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) which returns a [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) .. there is no thing like a `Transform2D`. I used what you provided as example .. if you have to deal with other types and actually can not use `transform` then please post a different example of the code you actually are using.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I'm allowed to share some actual snippet of it! But I figured it out already mostly basing from your answer and some minor changes. Thank you!